Running Regression in loop in R on all columns at once
head(Data)
                       
          Gene1 Gene2 Gene3 Gene4 Gene5 Gene6 Gene7 Gene8 Age Sex
  SAMPLE1   0    1      0      0     0     1   1     1     34  F   
  SAMPLE2   0    1      0      1     0     1   0     1     45  M
  SAMPLE3   0    0      0      1     0     0   1     1     35  M  
  SAMPLE4   1    0      0      0     1     0   0     0     36  F


I want to run logistic regression of every column against every column by adjusting age and sex.

Previously I applied chi square test this way.
``
com <- data.frame(t(combn(colnames(Data), 2)))
com`

`X1    X2
1  Gene1 Gene2
2  Gene1 Gene3
3  Gene1 Gene4
4  Gene1 Gene5
5  Gene1 Gene6
6  Gene1 Gene7
7  Gene1 Gene8
8  Gene2 Gene3

 chisq <- apply(com, 1, function(i) chisq.test(table(Data[,i]))$p.value)
